# Parsing JSON with dynamic json key using retrofit in MVVM pattern

Tags: android, json, kotlin, retrofit

I am trying to parse this json in android using retrofit. From the internet I can understand that I need to use GSON and type-token to get type but how when using Retrofit. Below is the JSON

```
{
  "temp": false,
  "event": {
    "2021-02-02": [
      {
        "name": "National Press Day"
      }
    ],
    "2021-02-09": [
      {
        "name": "Martyrs day"
      }
    ],
    "2021-02-24": [
      {
        "name": "public holiday"
      },
      {
        "name": "Folk Music day"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

As you can see that the date attribute is dynamic. I have made all the model classes but don't know how to use it with retrofit.  Below it my network related code

```
object RetrofitProvider {
    var retrofit: Retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(BuildConfig.BASE_URL)
        .client(OkhttpClient.client)
        .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()

    fun <T> createAPI(service: Class<T>): T {
        return retrofit.create(service)
    }
}

object OkhttpClient {

    val client: OkHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .writeTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .addInterceptor(okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor().apply {
            level = if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)
                okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
            else
                okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.NONE
        }  )
        .build()
}
```

In my repository, I invoke method to fetch data from above json

```
repository.getHolidays(RequestDTO(BuildConfig.API_KEY, startDate = "2021-02-01", endDate = "2021-02-28"))
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe({ holidayList ->
                    Log.d("Holidays", "fetchHolidays: "+holidayList)
                    holidays.postValue(Resource.success(holidayList))
                }, { throwable ->
                    holidays.postValue(Resource.error("Something Went Wrong", null))
                })
```

I am getting value of event attribute of json as null and false value of temp attribute. Event attribute value is null probably because I intend to. fetch it in hashmap using type-token but dont know how to do it in conjunction with retrofit. Below are model classes

```
data class ResponseDTO(private val error: Boolean, private val holiday: Event)

data class Event(val hashMap: HashMap<String, List<EEHolidays>>)

data class EEHolidays(private val name: String)
```

Comment: Please share data class too

Comment: Data classes are now added in the original question